# How is binding working between components in this tutorial with "controlled components"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding

see here:  (https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

It's the basic tutorial on the react website.

I've reach a point in this tutorial where I'm confused as to what is happening I've read up to and a little past **"Lifting Up State"** section:

```
  class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
        {/* value is passed in from renderSquare from Board component */}
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  /*Passing data in form of props to Square Component with method*/
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(undefined)
    };
  }


handleClick(i){
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = 'X';
    this.setState({squares:squares});
  }
```

At this point I *believe* the Square component is accessed and rendered into the Board component, but I am confused on this line, for the handler prop: `onClick ={()=>this.handleClick(i)}`

I don't know how the handler that is presumably being accessed by       `<button className="square" onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>` inside the Square component is being bound? **Is it being bound to the parent component through the arrow function (because arrow functions set their `this` reference to be bound at execution), or is react doing this for me, or is it something else?**

I understand that the end point of this is that the parent is ultimately setting the state of the components, but I don't really understand how..

I might be misusing some terminology.

```
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square 
             value={this.state.squares[i]}
             onClick ={()=>this.handleClick(i)}
             />;
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: Frank';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Are you asking about function-binding specifically, or about the general approach? (`Board` renders `Square` and passes the event handler `handleClick` through props, `Square` then uses this handler when the button is clicked)

Comment: The function-binding, I understand the general approach, I'm just trying to figure out through what mechanism `Square` is able to access its state through `handleClick`?

Comment: It doesn't access any state, where do you see that?

Comment: `this.setState({squares:squares});` which is in the handler that given to `Square` ? Sorry for confusing you. I think I figured it out but I might just need to read the docs more to find what I'm looking for.